# Display a specific level of a category tree in WP

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, hierarchy

I'm trying to find a way to display a specific category level of a post.

For example. I have a post with a hierarchical category tree structure like below...

Parent cat

-Child cat A

--Child cat B

---Child cat C

I'm looking for a nifty piece code I can use within the loop that will allow me to display any of the category levels, not all the levels.

Comment: Found the answer but I can't post it here... https://goo.gl/Rydsul

Answer (score 0):

You might find some helpful information here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

I think especially the "depth" and "child_of" arguments will be interesting for your concern :)